# Generate events from react components within Pux

Tags: reactjs, purescript, purescript-pux

I'm trying to integrate a react component (https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest) within a Pux application, but failing to see how to raise events to be handled by the Pux event loop.

react-autosuggest takes an [explicit `onChange` callback](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest#inputpropsonchange-required) which gets fed with the new value plus some information on how things changed. I've tried passing in something like:

`onChange : (\ev -> QueryChange (targetValue ev))`

and while I can see this being called, it only constructs the event, rather than doing anything with it. The [`renderToReact` code](https://github.com/alexmingoia/purescript-pux/blob/1118d73e5f6c62225546a2156059156f68905775/src/Pux/Renderer/React.purs) suggests I want to get hold of `app.input`, but of course I don't have that in the `view` function.